# Radio buttons issue with OR javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, operator-keyword

Could somebody help me to understand the correct syntax for the OR operator in JavaScript. I am using || in my script but does not work. I have a radio button list with 4 values. I would like a drop down list to be visible on value 2 or 3. I can get it working no problem with a single value of 2 but no dice when I add || 3. Could anyone advise? Thanks in advance.

```
    function ShowConvert() {
        if (radConvert.GetValue() == 2 || 3) {
            frmActivate.GetItemByName("ConvertHide").SetVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            frmActivate.GetItemByName("ConvertHide").SetVisible(false);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(radConvert.GetValue() == 2 || radConvert.GetValue() == 3)

2||3 =2
```

|| means if left not falsy use right

eg.

```js
function(option){
option = option || {};
}
```

Comment: YanJun you are a saviour. It works perfectly and you made your explanation simple to understand. Thanks a lot. Hope you have a good day to yourself! Paul

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `||` operator in javascript, you are effectively splitting your if statement into two separate statements to be evaluated. If either of them is true, the if statement evaluates to true. Let's look at your condition:

```
if (radConvert.GetValue() == 2 || 3) {
```

Firstly, javascript will look at the section before the `||` operator, and see if it evaluates to `true`.

```
radConvert.GetValue() == 2
```

In this case, let's say that this isn't true - GetValue() is not returning 2. Because the statement evaluates to false, javascript now needs to look at the second half of your if condition.

Looking on the other side of the `||` operator, javascript just sees `3`. Javascript sees this as a "truthy" value. Since you're not actually comparing 3 to anything, javascript has to decide whether 3 should equate to `true` or `false`. The spec says that 3 is true, so the if statement as a whole evaluates to true, and your code in the statement runs.

The simplest fix is to call your method on both sides of the `||` operator -

```
if(radConvert.GetValue() == 2 || radConvert.GetValue() == 3) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Hecksa, Thanks so much for your concise explanation and answer. I have read through it and learned a lot. I had already gave Yanjun the big tick for his answer before I saw yours but thanks again for taking the time to help me. Cheers. Paul